# Facing issue Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, keystore

I'm facing below issue for my Spring Boot project which is on Java8.

***ISSUE***

I/O error on POST request for "https://testservice/find": Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
java.lang.Exception: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://testservice/find": Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://testservice/find": Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset.

***REST CONFIGURATION:***

```
public class RestTemplateConfig {
public RestTemplate getRestTemplate()
KeyStore identityKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream("MY.jks")) {
                identityKeyStore.load(in, "test123".toCharArray());
            }
            SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
                    .loadKeyMaterial(identityKeyStore,
                            "test123".toCharArray()
                    ).build();
            HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
            clientBuilder.useSystemProperties().setSSLContext(sslContext).
                    setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier()).disableCookieManagement().disableAuthCaching();
            CloseableHttpClient client = clientBuilder.build();
            HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
            factory.setHttpClient(client);
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
return restTemplate;
}
```

```
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
            HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(Translator.getApiRequest(1213), headers);
            ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplateConfig.getRestTemplate().exchange(apiurl, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
            return responseEntity.toString();
```

My suspect is spring boot is doing some thing with HTTP basic configuration behind the picture or my rest template is  not configured properly. Can anyone assist me please here ?

and I believe configuring my keystore to rest template is right ? please correct if something is incorrect.